# Error when I run my app on API 19

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

the app I'm working on works well on Lollipop and above but when I try on KitKat, it gives this error.

```
  W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
E/OpenGLRenderer: MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
E/OpenGLRenderer: MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
```

Below is my gradle. Any suggestions? Also, how can I make my app run on KitKat or Jelly bean? Thank you in advance.

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 21
        buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.wear.sms.smswearschool"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 21
            versionCode 4
            versionName "1.1"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        } }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        } }

    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } }


    dependencies { 
        //    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include:  ['*.jar']) 
        //    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12' 
        //    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

        compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.3'
        compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'
        compile 'com.commit451:PhotoView:1.2.4'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'

        compile "com.android.support:support-v4:+"
        compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
        compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'

        compile 'com.twotoasters.jazzylistview:library:1.2.1'
        compile 'com.twotoasters.jazzylistview:library-recyclerview:1.2.1'

        compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.7.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
        compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.0'

    //    Calender
        compile 'me.nlmartian.silkcal:library:0.1.1'
        ///
        compile 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.6.0'
        //
        compile 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.1.0'
        compile 'com.pushbots:pushbots-lib:2.0.13@aar'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.1.0' }
```

Comment: Many LogCat messages labeled with `E/` do not represent real problems. If you are experiencing symptoms beyond just those messages, please post a [mcve]. That would include the Java code that is triggering those messages, plus details of exactly what is going wrong in the app.

Comment: Are you testing on a virtual environment such as GenyMotion? Increase the memory available for GPU.

Comment: I don't think your code should compile with that Gradle file. Especially `support:support-v4:+"` because pluses are bad and you even duplicate that dependency

Answer (score 0):

Try running the app on a device with higher gpu memory... Maybe a phone